# how to change email for user and confirm it using usercreationform - django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

how to change email for user and confirm it using usercreationform , i want allow user to change email in his profile and when he enter new email he must activate email to save it in his profile

forms.py :

```
# Profile Form
class EmailChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True,label='Email',widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control center container','style': 'width:85%;text-align: center;background-color:#f6f6f6','placeholder':' Enter Your New E-mail '}) )
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'email',
            ]
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).count():          raise forms.ValidationError('Email is already in use, please check the email or use another email')
        return email
```

views.py :

```
# Edit Profile View
class EmailChange(UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = EmailChangeForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    template_name = 'user/commons/EmailChange.html'
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user
```

urls.py :

```
from django.urls import path
from blog_app.views import SignUpView, ProfileView, ActivateAccount,EmailChange

urlpatterns = [
    path('profile/change-email/me/', EmailChange.as_view(), name='emailchange'),
    path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', ActivateAccount.as_view(), name='activate'),
]
```

change email html page :

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" style="background-color:#7952b3" value=" change ">
</form>
```

Comment: I have same problem